# xml parse with object field

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following xml

```
<django-objects version="1.0">
<object pk="4613" model="customers.customer">
<field type="CharField" name="username">User A</field>
<field type="CharField" name="email"/>
<field type="BooleanField" name="activo">1</field>
<field type="CharField" name="address">street zz</field>
</object>
<object pk="4644" model="customers.customer">
<field type="CharField" name="username">User B</field>
<field type="CharField" name="email"/>
<field type="BooleanField" name="activo">1</field>
<field type="CharField" name="address">street bla bla</field>
</object>
```

trying to parse it using

> $xml = simplexml_load_string($url);

and then

> foreach ($xml->object as $dato) {    print_r($dato['pk']); }

Works Fine.. but I need to extract username... how can I do it?

Comment: so what does `$dato['pk']` print out? That should give you a pretty good idea how to get the username.

Comment: it prints likes SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 4613 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 4644 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to get the username with the following;

```
foreach ($xml->object as $dato) {
    echo $dato->field[0];

}
```

As you're looping through each object, you want to get the first field element of each object.